# Spring-test not finding SpringRunner class in tests

Tags: spring-boot

When I use the SpringInitializr to generate a new project and include spring-test, all is good...except one thing.  The one test it creates cannot resolve the SpringRunner class.  It includes an @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) and from everything that I read this should be valid with spring-boot 1.5.9.  Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I'm using Eclipse.  From what I see in the Maven dependencies, things look OK.  It's using the spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar.  I open it up and see that it has the SpringRunner class.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Any project that I create from SpringInitializr is the same (and I create it in SpringInitializer using the 1.5.9 default)

Test class is out of the box:

```
    package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

--UPDATE...so, I can revert in the pom.xml file the spring-test minor version...from 4.3.13 to 4.3.12 and it finds it.  It seems to just be the most current (recommended) version of the 4.3.x major release.  At this point, I have a workaround but would like to be current if anyone has ideas.  As I mentioned above, I can bust open the 4.3.13 jar file and find the SpringRunner class

Comment: one addition...if I run the initializer under the 1.4.7 version eclipse finds SpringRunner.class

Comment: Paste your test class too

Comment: updated post with the test class

Answer (score 0):

Update spring-boot-starter-parent to 2.0.1.RELEASE

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
<relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
```

Comment: This was carry over from where I tried to make it work...and how I found that it was a 2.x issue I was dealing with